# How to auto-refresh page after Visualforce Error

Tags: apex, class, error

is there any way to refresh page after an Visualforce error: like 'Unable to lock row'
please I need help, i was trying to use window.onerror to reload the page but that doesn't work. so I was curious if SF provides some type of recovery after an exception occurs.

This control is  for an API that runs all day long, so jquery checks for the size of the list and when is equals to 0 starts again. So the page do not need human interaction at all if there are no errors.

I will appreciate any help!

code with try and catch block

```
try{
         update nr;


  }catch (Exception e) {



  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No completely sure if this will work but it may:

```
try{
         database.update(nr,false);


  }catch (Exception e) {



  }
```

But if it does work you will have no indication that an error occurred.

Comment: hello Eric, I will test it right now and I will let u know ! thank you !

Comment: do u know why window.onerror doesn't work?

Comment: Are you getting the error in the white screen or is it in the page messages? If it is in the white screen then you cannot catch that error. window.onerror is a java error handler IIRC and the unable to lock rows is not a java error.

Comment: the Page turns white and says VisualForce Error and the error message

Comment: but so far i am not getting the error, could you please explain me whats the difference a regulat `update nr` and `database.update(nr,false);`

Comment: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_dml_database.htm

Comment: Eric, great information in the link.  Apparently the code is working just fine. I let you know if the error shows up. thanks again man and I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Eric, i hope you are doing well. I am getting a new error: `System.QueryException: Record Currently Unavailable:` Your solution worked perfectly for this error: 'Unable to lock row' Any ideas why this new error is not getting caught. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Set your action method to return a PageReference, then in your exception catcher simply:

return null;

This will refresh the page.

Comment: @Carlos - Give this a shot and let us know if it works as well.

Comment: Hi DavinC, let me explain you, this control is  for an API that runs all day long, so jquery checks for the size of the list and when is equals to 0 starts again. So the page do not need human interaction at all if there are no errors.

Comment: If there any reason why refreshing everytime (regardless of success / error) wouldn't work? It seems like the simplest option.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript to reload to page based on attributes of an visible or invisible element of the DOM.

You need to make sure that the javascript is invoked on Errors.

Comment: Hi Uwe Heim, i am new in SF so could you please give me more details about your solution? i will really appreciate it